# Feign client and param for get

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign

Here is my configuration class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "partner.broker.agreements.rest-client")
public class BrokerAgreementsRestConfig extends RestClientConfig {
    private String investApiKey;
}
```

I need to send get-request via FeignClient. My request must have one header with a key:

```
@FeignClient(name = "brokerAgreements", url = "${partner.broker.agreements.rest-client.baseUrl}")
public interface BrokerAgreementsRestClient {

    String X_APP_HEADER = "x-app-name=bundle";
    String X_API_KEY = "x-api-key=%s";
    String X_INVEST_API = String.format(X_API_KEY, new BrokerAgreementsRestConfig().getInvestApiKey());

    @GetMapping(path = "broker-account/siebel/{siebelId}",
            consumes = APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            headers = {X_APP_HEADER, X_INVEST_API})
    BrokerAccountsRs getBrokerAccounts(@PathVariable(value = "siebelId") String siebelId, @RequestBody String requestBody);
}
```

But my IDE says that headers are incorrect and my `X_INVEST_API` should be a constant. As I know, all the objects are initialized in an interface are final. What's wrong and why does it requier a constant?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to use a header with a dynamic value like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066331/using-headers-with-dynamic-values-in-feign-client-spring-cloud-brixton-rc2) :