# How to propagate token using Spring Feign Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I am using Feign Client to call another microservice as below:

```
@FeignClient("employee")
public interface EmployeeFeignClient {

    @RequestMapping(
        method= RequestMethod.GET,
        value="/employee/code/{code}",
        consumes="application/json"
    )
    EmployeeResponseEntity getEmployeeByCode(@PathVariable("code") String code);
}
```

The service which calls the employee service will have authentication bearer token in its request header. I need to pass this same token to the service call being made.
Tried to find on how to achieve the same but could not. Some help would be nice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using @Headers with dynamic values in Feign client + Spring Cloud (Brixton RC2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066331/using-headers-with-dynamic-values-in-feign-client-spring-cloud-brixton-rc2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was answered before.

The solution is to use @RequestHeader annotation instead of feign specific annotations

```
@FeignClient(name="Simple-Gateway")
interface GatewayClient {    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/gateway/test")
    String getSessionId(@RequestHeader("X-Auth-Token") String token);
}
```